# Think I need a Self Join?

Tags: php, mysql, self-join

I have a table with the following structure:

```
id, Metal, AmPm, GBP, USD, EUR, Updated, TimeStamp
```

Sample values include:

```
INSERT INTO `LondonFixes` (`id`, `Metal`, `AmPm`, `GBP`, `USD`, `EUR`, `Updated`, `TimeStamp`) VALUES
(228, 'Gold', 'AM', '1779.22000', '2748.00000', '2253.20000', '2012-07-13', '2012-07-13 15:19:35'),
(224, 'Gold', 'PM', '1022.33700', '1579.00000', '1294.05000', '2012-07-13', '2012-07-13 13:16:59'),
```

I have queried the data and am able to get the last 10 rows and order them how I want as follows:

```
    $r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM(SELECT id, GBP, AmPm, Updated FROM LondonFixes WHERE Metal = 'Gold' AND UPDATED < now() ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) AS src ORDER BY id ASC");
```

This returns a table of the form:

```
id, GBP, AmPm, Updated
```

The problem is that I need a table of the form:

```
id, GBP_AM, GBP_PM, Updated
```

Basically, AmPm values can either contain the values "AM" or "PM". I want to show the GBP value for both AM and PM on one line where updated is the same on both lines.

e.g. Required output based on above sample data:

```
1, 1779.22000, 1022.33700, 2012-07-13
```

I think that this is a self Join, but I just don't understand self joins and I am not even sure that Self Joins is what I need.

Comment: I think it would help if you could post some of the sample data from your database.

Comment: I removed the PHP `$r = mysql_query(...)` wrapper from the code as your question is more about the query itself and not about PHP returning it. However, if someone finds it relevant it can still be found in the edit history.

Comment: Where does the `1` come from in the `id` field for your desired output?

Comment: The 1 is made up by me. I thought because it was a new type of table, it would have a new id value.

Comment: Clarify exactly what you want to do with the `Timestamp` field and I could provide a more helpful query. My answer below will possibly produce too many combinations.

Comment: @J.Miller - My Query can ignore the TimeStamp Field. This timestamp is just the datetime that the query was inserted. I want to work with the Updated field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to incur the overhead of a self-join. Instead, simply do it with conditional checking:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
(
      SELECT MAX(CASE AmPm WHEN 'AM' THEN GBP END) AS GBP_AM,
             MAX(CASE AmPm WHEN 'PM' THEN GBP END) AS GBP_PM,
             Updated
        FROM LondonFixes
       WHERE Updated < CURDATE() AND Metal = 'Gold'
    GROUP BY Updated
    ORDER BY Updated DESC
       LIMIT 10
) a
ORDER BY a.Updated
```

This is assuming the `id` field is not important to you. I'm excluding it in my solution.

Comment: This does work for the given input data and sample output (when I adjust the where to accommodate the fact the the dates are not `< CURDATE()` ;-) ), but I can't help feeling you should be grouping by `Metal` for use in the real world...

Comment: This solution certainly looks neater. I will try this one and the one by J.Miller to test. May take me half hour or so to get my head round it!!!

Comment: @DaveRandom, the OP states in the question "*I want to show the GBP value for both AM and PM on one line where updated is the same on both lines.*", so the `GROUP BY` would need to happen on the `Updated` field.

Comment: @Gravy, I'm questioning whether you even need to check if the updated field is less than `NOW()`. If `Updated` always gets inserted with the present date, and not sometime in the future, you don't need to check if it's less than the current date. =)

Comment: @ZaneBien - I have < NOW() for specific reasons. I don't want today's results to be included in the list. e.g. I want results older than today. Updated is the date that the AM / PM GBP value was provided. Not the date that it was inserted into system. Updated and TimeStamp are very different things.

Comment: @Gravy: Okay, got it! I updated my answer to use `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in .....

Comment: @Gravy, make sure the column names are correct and that there aren't hidden characters mucking up the query. It works great in the [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf050/2/0).

Comment: Aaaah!!! Works perfectly now. Copied and pasted from SQLFiddle. Thank you for your help!!! :)

Answer (score 3):

Self-join just means you join a copy of the table onto itself, and works like any other join.

```
SELECT a.GBP AS GBP_AM, b.GBP AS GBP_PM, a.Updated
FROM LondonFixes a
JOIN LondonFixes b ON(a.Updated = b.Updated AND a.Metal = b.Metal)
WHERE a.AmPm = 'AM' AND b.AmPm = 'PM';
```

Comment: Drop the `id` from the field list and the `ON` clause and I think you've got it.

Comment: I just saw you wanted the selected ID to be something new... in which case you can use this query as a starting point. You'll probably need to fiddle with filtering the timestamp, sorting, etc.

Comment: @J.Miller In this context I suspect the id is irrelevant to usage (it doesn't reference a single row in a useful way any more) and could be dropped from the field list entirely.

Comment: @all - the id was just for the sorting of the results. I am looking for the last 10 entries but I want them in order of the Updated Date. I suppose I could always sort by Updated instead of id